# Is it possible to use a tracing image for view design within Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, interface-builder

The UI for many iOS applications are either wireframed or fully designed prior to implementation.

The process of building a UI within IB is generally visually mimicking placement and design, but isn't there an easier and more accurate way to to this?  Can't the design be loaded as a temporary background to aid placement?

Does IB support the ability to load an image as a temporary view background so that UI elements can be placed and scaled using the image as a guideline?

If not, is there a trick to this? Using an `UIImageView`, perhaps? Devoting a new layer to it? If so, what's the best way to incorporate a tracing image that without creating problems getting rid of it later?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, as you mentioned, is adding a `UIImageView` to your view controllers’ views with the frame of the view’s bounds. To prevent unintentional focusing/replacing, [lock it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2268049/3151675).

To ensure maximal accuracy, [set the size of your VC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17871614/3151675) in Interface Builder to the size of the reference design.

For a third-party solution, you can also try out [Flawless](https://flawlessapp.io/), although it only works in the iOS Simulator.